# Import data into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I need to import data from a file into a Microsoft SQL Server database.

- The file is roughly structured (inconsistent number of fields but the data needed is available in all rows)
- The file can contain up to 600'000 records
- The first field is identifies a record

The import of the data contains updating existing records in the database with the new values or inserting a new record if the record could not be found.

What is the best approach to accomplish that?

(Reading the file line by line, executing a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` or `INSERT` from my .NET Application doesn't truly satisfy me, because this way it processes around 35 records per second, which leads to several hours of processing time...)

A first option might be to combine the select and update/insert commands in a stored procedure, but this would still take a lot of time.

Is there something like MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`?

Is it possible to pass a list/array of records (multiple columns) to a stored procedure?

If yes how is that implemented?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You should have a look at [SQL Server BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to bulk load a file into a staging table in SQL Server. Once you've loaded the data into a staging table, you can then detect and eliminate duplicates and fill the data into the "real" data tables.

Comment: How would you 'detect and eliminate duplicates' to fill the data into the target data table? As described, duplicates should be treated as `UPDATE` statements and all others as `INSERT` statements

Comment: Thanks. The MERGE was what I was looking for. You might want to add this as the answer so that I can flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [SQL Server BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to bulk load a file into a staging table in SQL Server.

Once you've loaded the data into a staging table, you can then use the [SQL Server 2008 MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to insert/update ("upsert") your actual data tables. That's exactly the scenario it's designed to solve...

Answer (score 0):

SSIS was created to do exactly that. [Here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/import-text-files-ssis/) is an example.

Comment: I haven't worked with SSIS yet. The import should run automatically (without user interaction) and without any dependencies on dev environments. What are the possibilites with SSIS there?

Comment: if you need to run it more than one time, build the package and add it to a schedule job. I suggest you give it a try, it is a very good technology